# Ubuntu/Lubuntu Wi-Fi Stopped Working after Screen Replacement/Wi-Fi Disconnect

Tags: wireless, networking, lubuntu

I changed the screen in my HP530 (so much cheaper than a new laptop).
I had to disconnect the wifi card in the process of opening the machine up. Now I have an unusual problem; the wifi works fine in Vista but booting in Lubuntu or Ubuntu, I see very weak signals for available networks and connecting to mine doesn't work anymore.

It's an Intel 3945ABG (Golan) wi-fi card and Lubuntu 12.10. Any ideas?

Comment: Run `lspci -v` and find your network controller. Post the output here.

Comment: Thanks, the wifi is: 10:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
 Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: iwl3945

Answer (score 0):

See the thread "[No wireless networks detected since latest kernel upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300284/no-wireless-networks-detected-since-latest-kernel-upgrades/300289#300289)" regarding /etc/network/interfaces configurations that helped another user with that card. If that does not work, try the steps below. Also, for the sake of basic troubleshooting, ensure that the card if firmly connected.

Your card requires non-free firmware. Try to (re-)install the iwlegacy driver. It can be [downloaded directly here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlegacy) or you can add this repository `deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free` to /etc/apt/sources.list and install with `apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi` I went ahead and confirmed that it is in fact in the repository at this time. ([From Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/iwlegacy))

Remove and load the module for your device:

```
modprobe -r iwl3945
modprobe iwl3945
```