# no wireless networks detected since latest kernel upgrades

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, kernel

Unable to detect wireless network since kernel  3.2.0-41.  Problem began immediately following kernel upgrade

```
lspci -nn |grep 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43227 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4358]

sudo modprobe wl
FATAL: Module wl not found.
FATAL: Error running install command for wl

sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: dc:0e:a1:96:10:9d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.121 duplex=full firmware=sb ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:c0430000-c043ffff memory:c0440000-c044ffff memory:c0450000-c04507ff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43227 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0500000-c0503fff

iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

rfkill list all
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

uname -a
Linux james-Aspire-5750Z 3.2.0-44-generic-pae #69-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 16 18:50:07 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

apt-cache policy bcmwl-kernel-source
bcmwl-kernel-source:
  Installed: 6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.1
  Candidate: 6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.1
  Version table:
 *** 6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.100.82.38+bdcom-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/restricted i386 Packages

lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
usbmouse               12666  0 
usbhid                 41937  0 
hid                    77428  1 usbhid
dm_crypt               22528  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31775  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   174313  1 
snd_hda_intel          32719  3 
snd_hda_codec         109562  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
joydev                 17393  0 
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80916  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51592  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    62218  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              14635  1 snd
uvcvideo               67203  0 
videodev               86588  1 uvcvideo
mei                    36570  0 
snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
acer_wmi               23612  0 
sparse_keymap          13658  1 acer_wmi
i2c_i801               17346  0 
psmouse                86520  0 
serio_raw              13027  0 
rfcomm                 38139  0 
pcspkr                 12614  0 
bnep                   17830  2 
evbug                  12581  0 
bluetooth             158479  10 rfcomm,bnep
parport_pc             32114  0 
mac_hid                13077  0 
ppdev                  12849  0 
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
sdhci_pci              18324  0 
sdhci                  28241  1 sdhci_pci
tg3                   141414  0 
i915                  428014  3 
drm_kms_helper         45466  1 i915
drm                   197641  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
wmi                    18744  1 acer_wmi
video                  19115  1 i915
```

Please advise.
:) Thanks !

Comment: try to re-install the kernels .http://askubuntu.com/questions/287794/how-to-reenable-networking-wireless-still-not-working/287895#287895

Comment: Reinstalled the kernels.  Still no wireless networks detected.@jai

Comment: I have exactly the same problem except I have an Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem except that I have an Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG wireless card.

My solution was to reset my `/etc/network/interfaces` file to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

This solved my issue however this post ([What's the default /etc/network/interfaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214170/whats-the-default-etc-network-interfaces)) indicated that the default `/etc/network/interfaces` file should look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface -- use DHCP to find our address
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1). Run Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

2). Paste the commands into Terminal one at a time using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy from your browser then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste in to Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and finally

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Hope this makes it clear

Comment: entered those three commands.  Here is the result of `sudo modprobe wl`:  FATAL: Module wl not found.
FATAL: Error running install command for wl

Comment: test @SimplySimon