# No wireless in kernel 3.9.0

Tags: wireless, 13.04, kernel

I get wireless when booting the older version, 3.8.0, but no sound, so I'm choosing to fix wireless on 3.9.0 as it seems easier. I am on Ubuntu 13.04.
Here's my wireless adapter:

```
lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

I tried re-installing using this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx but no luck

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [no wireless networks detected since latest kernel upgrades](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300284/no-wireless-networks-detected-since-latest-kernel-upgrades)

Answer (score 0):

Install the one in Software Sources > Additional Drivers ?

[image: Software Sources]

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the current version of bcmwl-kernel-source module available in the ubuntu repository. Have a look @ https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1157880

I installed the patched module available @ https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu3/+build/4761504 (as specified in that bug) and I got my wireless working with 3.10.2 kernel version :)

```
    hprem@hprem-mac:~$ sudo dpkg -i Downloads/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
    Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
    (Reading database ... 305414 files and directories currently installed.)
    Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (from .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
    Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu3) ...
    Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.30+bdcom DKMS files...
    Building only for 3.10.2-031002-generic
    Building for architecture x86_64
    Building initial module for 3.10.2-031002-generic

    Done.

    wl:
    Running module version sanity check.
     - Original module
       - No original module exists within this kernel
     - Installation
       - Installing to /lib/modules/3.10.2-031002-generic/updates/dkms/

    depmod....

    DKMS: install completed.
    update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
    Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.10.2-031002-generic
    hprem@hprem-mac:~$

hprem@hprem-mac:~$ lshw -c network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 02
       serial: 28:cf:e9:1d:20:27
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.30 (r390414) ip=64.103.81.25 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:17 memory:c1900000-c1903fff
```

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer in [more than one place](http://askubuntu.com/a/324163/22949). When tempted to do so, typically: (1) the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), (3) the answer should really be a comment, **or** (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing bcmwl kernel source from launchpad. You need to install the package for saucy and wireless works again. Its kind of upgrade for the default bcmwl driver in ubuntu.
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl

download and install the one for saucy and it will work.